# Default API Filters Failing when referencing nested properties of related entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I am configuring a series of ApiFilter classes from the Api-platform stack in a Symfony 4 application. I am finding that any filters using a nested property from an entity relationship takes no effect.  Please see my example code below, would really appreciate any assistance with why it may not be working.

The entity I am trying to filter on is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty;

/**
 * PostAuthor
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Table(name="POST_AUTHOR", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_CF3397D94A7000A0", columns={"IDENTITY_ID"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostAuthorRepository")
 */
class PostAuthor
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="USER_ID", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="USERNAME", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $username;
```

And the collection I am filtering is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\NumericFilter;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * PostHeader
 * @ORM\Table(name="POST_HEADER", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_1CEEE7D0B65E5FF8", columns={"EMOTION_REF_ID"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_1CEEE7D08AFAAB14", columns={"AUTHOR_ID"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PostHeaderRepository")
 * @ApiResource(
 *       normalizationContext={"groups"={"postheader:read"}},
 *       denormalizationContext={"groups"={"postheader:write"}},
 *    )
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"author.userId": "partial", "author.username": "partial"})
 */
class PostHeader
{

 /**
     * @var PostAuthor
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PostAuthor")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({@ORM\JoinColumn(name="AUTHOR_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_ID")})
     * @Groups({"postheader:read"})
     */
    private $author;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just test on a new project with the same classes than you and it works. I can filter by author.userId.
Please give us your testing request. And the error message ;).

Comment: There is no error message, just an unfiltered list.  I am simply using the default api-platform symfony implementation, no customisation. The filters work in the /api test area, producing request urls such as /index.php/post_headers?author.userId=XXXX.

However on the admin the route parameters are formatted differently, as follows: 
/index.php/api/post_headers?author%5BuserId%5D=XXXX,  when I look at the request stack of this it generates a signicantly different parameter pattern.

I wonder if this is contributing the my issue.